# How get the max length value of an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, linq

I'm an amateur in C#; I'm trying to convert this function of VB.Net to C#...

```
<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)> _
<Extension()> _
Public Function mc_GetMaxLengthValue(ByVal Values() As String) As String
    mc_GetMaxLengthValue = ""

    If Values.Count > 0 Then mc_GetMaxLengthValue = Values.OrderByDescending(Function(Value) Value.Length).First
End Function
```

I can't figure it out how convert the `OrderByDescending(Function(Value) Value.Length)`.

In terms of the functionality, I want to get the max length in the array. Ex: {"123456", "123", "1234"}. I want to get "123456" (The longest string).

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read a LINQ tutorial in C#. It will answer this and a *lot* more, in a nicely structured way. (If nothing else, look at the example code for OrderByDescending in MSDN.)

Comment: What have you tried to do so far, and what problems are you having with your attempted solutions?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @MiBol `I'm an amateur in C#` Just explain what this function do and I am going to post an answer.

Comment: @L.B: I want to get the max length in the array. Ex: {"123456", "123", "1234"}. I want to get 6 (The length of the longest string)

Comment: @MiBol but your vb code returns the longest string, not the length of it. This is why I asked it. You don't even know what it does. If that were the case the answer would be `Values.Max(x=>x.Length)`

Comment: @MiBol Why do you need a function you don't know what is does?

Comment: @L.B: My fault!, I used the result with vResult.Length() to get the length. In the case that I want to retrieve the longest string? how you can do it?

Comment: @MiBol `OrderBy + First` has a time complexity `O(n*log(n))`. on the other hand, `Max` has `O(n)`. Decide what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Values.OrderByDescending(o => o.Length).First()  //max value
list.Max(o => o.Length) //max length
```

Comment: Code is correct.  May need to include System.Linq.  However just noticed your looking for the length and not the value.  Use Neolisk's answer.

Comment: how do you see Neolisk's answer. your reps are not enough. Is this your second account?

Comment: He deleted his response.  I modified my answer.

Comment: I don't see anything similar to `list.Max(o => o.Length)` in Neolisk's answer.

Comment: If I remember correctly he did a .Select(o => o.Length).Max().  Essentially the same thing.  Mine is more concise.

Comment: Yes you remember it correctly :)